# selecting specific rows etc. using ddply

Tags: r, plyr

I have a three part question based on a dataframe (df is example rows) of goals scored by soccer players in a season

```
 Player           Season  Goals
 Teddy Sheringham 1992/3   22
 Les Ferdinand    1992/3   20
 Dean Holdsworth  1992/3   19
 Andy Cole        1993/4   34
 Alan Shearer     1993/4   31
 Chris Sutton     1993/4   25
```

If I want to obtain the top scorer each year I can use

```
ddply(df, "Season", summarise, maxGoals = max(Goals),
      Player=Player[which.max(Goals)])
```

**Questions:**

1) It does not apply in this case but does this suffice if there are joint top scorers

2) I am also interested in the runner up for each season being extracted. I have played around with sorting on Goals descending and index 2 but have not found solution

3) Also how would I obtain a count value for each year based on number of Goals scored e.g Goals>20 should give 1 for 1992/3 and 3 for 1993/4 on the above data

Comment: You should use `dput` to create a reproducible version of your dataframe, it would help people answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are multiple best players, that expression will report only one of them (specifically, the first in the dataframe in that year).

For q2:

```
d = ddply(df, "Season", summarise, SecondPlayer=Player[order(Goals)[length(Goals)-1]])
```

For q3:

```
d = ddply(df, "Season", summarise, Count=sum(Goals > 20))
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll follow up the dput suggestion. You seem to have understood my problem anyways :)

Answer (score 1):

1+2) No, it is not sufficient. You might have better luck looking at the `unique` values under `Goals`, and grabbing the rows corresponding to the appropriate value in that case. Maybe something like,

```
myFun <- function(x,k){
    val <- sort(unique(x$Goals))
    Players <- x$Players[x$Goals == val[k]]
    data.frame(Players = Players, maxGoals = rep(val[k],length(Players)))
}

ddply(df,.(Season),myFun,k = 1)
```

where you can specify if you want the players with the most, second most, etc number of goals using the parameter `k`. (This is untested, obviously, so some minor modifications may be necessary.)

Comment: thanks for suggestion. I'll follow it up. Kinda surprised there is not a simpler solution as must be a common occurrence

Comment: @pssguy I think we may have slightly different notions of what a "simple solution" looks like. :)

Comment: Anything with more than 20 brackets gets my head spinning!