# Removing records from a data frame based on comparison to other records

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
Reach Chem HQ 
a Mercury 1.12
a Nickel  1.65
b Mercury 1.54
b Nickel 2.34
b Cadmium 3.12
c Mercury 2.12
c Nickel 2.34
```

I would like to strip down the data frame by only keeping the record for each `Reach` with the highest `HQ`, resulting in this:

```
 Reach Chem HQ 
 a Nickel  1.65
 b Cadmium 3.12
 c Nickel 2.34
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a one liner (or close to) method in base R.

Get the data:

```
test <- read.table(textConnection("Reach Chem HQ 
a Mercury 1.12
a Nickel  1.65
b Mercury 1.54
b Nickel 2.34
b Cadmium 3.12
c Mercury 2.12
c Nickel 2.34"),header=TRUE)
```

Return the row in each `Reach` group that has the highest `HQ` using `by` and `which.max`
The `do.call(rbind...` just joins the identified rows together into a single dataset.

```
do.call(rbind,by(test,test$Reach,function(x) x[which.max(x$HQ),]))
```

Result:

```
  Reach    Chem   HQ
a     a  Nickel 1.65
b     b Cadmium 3.12
c     c  Nickel 2.34
```

edit - to address mindless.panda and joran's discussion below regarding if there are ties in the maximum value, this will work:

```
do.call(rbind,by(test,test$Reach,function(x) x[x$HQ==max(x$HQ),]))
```

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you could try using ?order and ?duplicated like this:

```
my_df = data.frame(
    Reach = c("a","a","b","b","b","c","c"), 
    Chem = c("Mercury","Nickel","Mercury","Nickel","Cadmium","Mercury","Nickel"),
    HQ = c(1.12,1.65,1.54,2.34,3.12,2.12,2.34)
    )

my_df = my_df[order(my_df$HQ,decreasing=TRUE),]
my_df = my_df[!duplicated(my_df$Reach),]
my_df = my_df[order(my_df$Reach),]
```

Edit: Results shown below for clarity.

```
  Reach    Chem   HQ
2     a  Nickel 1.65
5     b Cadmium 3.12
7     c  Nickel 2.34
```

Answer (score 3):

If you like `plyr` methods:

```
data <- read.table(text="Reach Chem HQ 
a Mercury 1.12
a Nickel  1.65
b Mercury 1.54
b Nickel 2.34
b Cadmium 3.12
c Mercury 2.12
c Nickel 2.34", header=TRUE)

require(plyr)
ddply(data, .(Reach), summarize, Chem=Chem[which.max(HQ)], MaxHQ=max(HQ))

  Reach    Chem  MaxHQ
1     a  Nickel   1.65
2     b Cadmium   3.12
3     c  Nickel   2.34
```

**Edit:**

In part motivated by this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9874471/selecting-specific-rows-etc-using-ddply) and thinking about the cases where there are more than just one `Chem` type columns (columns not being subset on) and replicating `Chem=Chem[which.max(HQ)]` for each one would get verbose, I came up with this. I'm curious if a `plyr` wizard can weigh in if there are better ways to do this:

```
# add the within-group max HQ as a column
df <- ddply(data, .(Reach), transform, MaxHQByReach=max(HQ))

# now select the rows where the HQ equals the Max HQ, dropping the above column
subset(df, df$HQ==df$MaxHQByReach)[,1:(ncol(df)-1)]
```

Comment: If the OP wants to include duplicate max's, I would probably just use an anonymous function like: `function(x){ x[x$HQ == max(x$HQ),] }`.

Answer (score 2):

Hi you can also use max and lapply like this :

```
Reach <- unique(my_df$Reach)
        HQ <- unlist(lapply(1:length(unique(my_df$Reach)),function(x) max(my_df$HQ[which(my_df$Reach == unique(my_df$Reach)[x])])))

        Chem <- my_df$Chem[match(lapply(1:length(unique(my_df$Reach)),function(x) max(my_df$HQ[which(my_df$Reach == unique(my_df$Reach)[x])])),my_df$HQ)]

            new.df <- data.frame(Reach,Chem,HQ)
        new.df

          Reach    Chem   HQ
        1     a  Nickel 1.65
        2     b Cadmium 3.12
        3     c  Nickel 2.34
```